# Using ls and rbind_all to combine multiple data frames

Tags: r, rbind

I'm trying to use ls and rbind_all to combine multiple data.frames by row. Here's my code:

```
pc.files <- ls(pattern="*_pc") #look for all files with "_pc" at end
all.pc <- rbind_all(list(pc.files)) #rbind them
```

but!

```
Error: object at index 1 not a data.frame
```

Is this because pc.files is a character vector? All the *_pc datasets are data.frame. I can't work out why this isn't working..

thanks

Comment: You need to use `mget` to use the actual data frames rather than their *names* (a character vector as you said) contained in `pc.files`.

Comment: @mark I would read all the files into a list rather than creating multiple data.frames. For example.  If the files end with `_pc1.txt`, `_pc2.txt`, `library(data.table); rbindlist(lapply(list.files(pattern='^_pc\\d+'), fread))`

Comment: hi @akrun, using `rbindlist(lapply(list.files(pattern='^_pc\\d+'), fread))` returns a 0 obs 0 variables df. I have checked that the pattern regex works

Comment: @mark It must be something with the `fread` then.  Try using `lapply(list.files(...), function(x) read.table(x))`

Comment: `all.pc <- rbind_list(lapply(list.files(<mypatter>),function(x) read.table(x)))` takes a while to run but still returns 0 obs 0 variables df

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `mget`:

```
all.pc <- rbind_all(mget(pc.files))
```

Comment: Hi,thanks for comments. Trying `all.pc <- rbind_list(mget(pc.files))` returns a 0 obs 0 variables df. pc.files is character `> pc.files
 [1] "al.csv" "br.csv" "cm.csv" "cr.csv" "da.csv" "e.csv"  "ec.csv" "en.csv" "gu.csv" "ha.csv"
[11] "hp.csv" "ig.csv" "kt.csv" "me.csv" "n.csv"  "nw.csv" "rg.csv" "rh.csv" "rm.csv" "se.csv"
[21] "sg.csv" "sl.csv" "sm.csv" "ss.csv" "sw.csv" "tn.csv" "tw.csv" "ub.csv" "w.csv"  "wc.csv"
[31] "wd.csv"` (actually my files end .csv but they are dfs)

Comment: @mark Are you sure there is some data in the variables?

Comment: Yes they contain data `> head(br.csv)
  BR1.1AB X10 N X10.1 X10.2 X10.3 X0 X0.1 X1 X0.2 X540260 X169398 E92000001 E19000003 E18000007 X
1 BR1 1AD  50 N     1     0     0  1    0  0    1  540227  169300 E92000001 E19000003 E18000007 ...`   but `> all.pc <- rbind_all(mget(c("al.csv","br.csv")))` DOES gives a df of both "al.csv" and "br.csv" row bound

Comment: OK. In trying to answer both @James and @akrun (above) I incorrectly used `rbind_list` not `rbind_all` for @James's solution. Using `rbind_all` still threw the error `> all.pc <- rbind_all(mget(pc.files))
Error: incompatible type (data index: 7, column: 'V16', was collecting: integer (dplyr::Collecter_Impl<16>), incompatible with data of type: logical`This directed me to find a column with no data in my input dfs. Once this column removed from inputs the code `all.pc <- rbind_all(mget(pc.files))` works. Thanks all.